# Problema com moedas no Asp.Net Core MVC 6.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou enfrentando um problema bem estranho. Não consigo configurar um projeto para o padrão de moeda e textos para pt-BR. Já tentei muitas coisas e até agora, só consegui fazer funcionar com as casas decimais com ponto e a mensagem de erro padrão é em inglês. Nada que faça muda para pt-BR... Segue os prints das classes até o momento...

Encomendas.cs (Model)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "É obrigatório informar o valor do pedido")]
    //[Range(0, 9999.99)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    //[Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
    //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}")]
    [Display(Name = "Valor")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

Obs.: Os comentários são testes que foram feitos e sem sucesso até então.

Program.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();

        //correção do idioma...
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
        var localOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
        {
            DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(cultureInfo),
            SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { cultureInfo },
            SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { cultureInfo }
        };

        app.UseRequestLocalization(localOptions);

        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".";
        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
        cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
        //cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ".";
        //cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        //fim da correção do idioma...

        app.UseRouting();
```

Create.cshtml e Edit.cshtml

```
<div class="form-floating mb-3 form-group">
   <input asp-for="Valor" id="Valor" class="form-control" placeholder="Insira o valor do orçamento" />
   <label for="Valor">Valor*</label>
   <span asp-validation-for="Valor" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Arquivo csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

net6.0
    enable
    enable
    pt-BR
  
Seguem os prints de como o sistema está rodando

https://prnt.sc/v_LGUhPR6EBD

https://prnt.sc/66kq6JumFcKL

Não sei se é algum problema com o meu pc. Utilizo o Windows 11 Pro com todas as configurações regionais como pt-BR.

Obs.: Coloquei esse código no inicio das views para depuração e como pode ser visto nos prints, é exibido com a localidade correta...

```
@System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture
```

Não sei mais o que fazer. Obrigado desde já pessoal!

Comment: Falta informação ai pra ter mais certeza, mas aqui vão algumas dicas do que validar: 1- "Program.cs", tente setar isso no StartUp.Configure  2- não aparece no seu código o `app.UseMvc();`, mas se estiver usando isso, faça depois de setar a cultura.

Comment: Certo Ricardo porém, o StartUp.Configure e o app.UseMvc() são recursos do net5.0. Eu utilizo a versão 6 e até ocorre erro se tentar usar o app.UseMvc()

Comment: humm agora ficou melhor de entender... de qualquer forma, o `app.UseStaticFiles();` deveria vir após setar a culture, já tentou mover essa linha abaixo e testar?

Comment: Está funcionando dessa forma

Program.cs
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ",";
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalDigits = 2;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;

Só no front que tem que usar pontos para casas decimais mas no index exibe com vírgula. Não tá perfeito mas resolveu!